# Custom endpoint for `ros3` driver in `h5py`

Tags: python, amazon-s3, hdf5, h5py, ceph

`h5py` supports the native S3 driver for HDF5 (the `ros3` driver). We've enabled this with a local build of `HDF5`.

```
>>> import h5py
>>>
>>> print(f'Registered drivers: {h5py.registered_drivers()}')

Registered drivers: frozenset({ 'ros3', 'sec2', 'fileobj', 'core', 'family', 'split', 'stdio', 'mpio'})
```

We have a custom endpoint for our S3 service (not AWS). We run a Ceph/S3 service.

**Is there a way to specify the S3 endpoint?**

The [documentation here](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/file.html?highlight=ros3) makes no mention of it.

If we attempt to run the following we get a generic error that we presume has to do with the obvious missing endpoint.

```
>>> h5py.File(
  f, 
  driver='ros3', 
  aws_region=bytes('unused', 'utf-8'),  # unused by our S3 but required
  secret_id=bytes(access_key, 'utf-8'), 
  secret_key=bytes(secret_key, 'utf-8')
)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mycode.py", line 32, in <module>
    with h5py.File(f, driver='ros3', aws_region=b'west', secret_id=access_key, secret_key=secret_key) as fh5:
  File "opt/anaconda3/envs/smart_open_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 567, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr=swmr)
  File "opt/anaconda3/envs/smart_open_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 231, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 106, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (curl cannot perform request)
```

I checked that the commonly used environment variables `ENDPOINT` and `ENDPOINT_URL` were set, but had no effect.

Comment: What version of h5py are you using? (Your error messages match errors reported for the `ros3` driver in 3.7. There were was a problem with `ros3` authentication (which kwargs to enter) in 3.7 that is fixed in 3.8, and 3.8 supports `s3://location` URLs. For either version, add this to your code: `h5py._errors.unsilence_errors()`. It gives the complete HDF5 error stack and may help diagnose the error.

Comment: Adding `h5py._errors.unsilence_errors()` clearly shows that the URL is going to `aws` and not our custom endpoint. Are you saying that there's an S3 URL format that includes the endpoint? My current S3 URL is structured as `s3://bucket/path/file`

Comment: Well, we're 1/2 way there. :-) If you are running h5py 3.8, you can use a s3 URL like `s3://bucket/path/file`. However, if you are using h5py  3.7, it's not clear (to me) how you would do it. It looks like you _might_ use  `"http://s3_domain/bucket/path/file"` For example, for AWS it would be `f"http://s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/{bucket}/{file}"`

Comment: Expanding on above, in 3.7 AWS authentication is set if any of `aws_region, secret_id and secret_key` are set. However, it should only be set when all 3 are provided. The 3.7 logic gets tripped up if you only set 1 or 2, and you get an error message when you try to open the file.  This is fixed in 3.8 So, you either need to set ALL 3 values (for AWS) or NONE of them (eg use`=b''` for all 3). This assumes you want anonymous access without authentication to read public files.

Comment: Ah, yeah, with `filename='https://{endpoitn}/{bucket}/{path/file}` it gets past that and I get to a new error, `could not find "Content-Length" in response`. If you want to post that as an answer to this question, I'll accept it, and thank you! I'm going to work on this next error and will post a separate question if need be.

Comment: Oh, man, having fun, huh? Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check is the HDF5 error stack to diagnose the error. You can get it by adding this line to your code: `h5py._errors.unsilence_errors()`.

Now, if that doesn't work, here is some background on the `ros3` driver. It was added to h5py 3.7 (May, 2022). The initial implementation had a logic error with the `aws_region, secret_id and secret_key` keywords. In 3.7, AWS authentication is set ***if any of the keywords*** are input (not blank). However, it should only be set ***when all 3 keywords*** are input. The 3.7 logic gets tripped up if you only set 1 or 2. You will get an error message when you try to open the file. So, you either need to set ALL 3 values (for AWS) or NONE of them (eg use=b'' for all 3). This assumes you want anonymous access without authentication to read public files.

Note: The logic error is fixed in 3.8 (January, 2023).
In addition, 3.8 adds support for S3 URLs like this: `f's3://{endpoint}/{bucket}/{path/file}'`. In 3.7 you would have to do something like `f'https://{endpoint}/{bucket}/{path/file}'`

Comment: Correction here though. I have h5py 3.8 and the URL `s3://{endpoint}/{bucket}/{path/file}` did not work. Only the `https` URL.

Comment: Sorry about that...the h5py docs and GitHub notes say it _should work_ :-( More digging required.